# how to automatically recognize user when logged in,retrieve his data from db?

Tags: php

```
<?php
error_reporting(0); 
session_start(); 
if( $_SESSION["logging"]&& $_SESSION["logged"])
{
 print_secure_content();
}
else {
if(!$_SESSION["logging"])
{  
$_SESSION["logging"]=true;
loginform();
}
   else if($_SESSION["logging"])
   {
     $number_of_rows=checkpass();
     if($number_of_rows==1)
        {   
         $_SESSION[user]=$_GET[userlogin];
         $_SESSION[logged]=true;
         $_SESSION[user_id]=$row['id'];
         print"<h1>You have loged in successfully</h1>";
         print_secure_content();
        }
        else{
            print "Wrong password or username, please try again.".'<br/>';  
            loginform();
        }
    }
 }

function loginform()
{
print "Please enter your login information to proceed with our site.".'<br/>'.'<br/>';
print ("<table border='2'><tr><td>Username</td><td><input type='text' name='userlogin'     size'20'></td></tr><tr><td>Password</td><td><input type='password' name='password'       size'20'></td></tr></table>").'<br/>';
print "<input type='submit' >"; 
print "<h3><a href='registerform.php'>Register now!</a></h3>";  
print "<br><a href='admin.php'>Admin login</a><br>";
}

function checkpass()
{
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$conn=  mysql_connect($servername,$username)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("kviz",$conn);
$sql="select * from korisnici where name='$_GET[userlogin]' and       password='$_GET[password]'";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
return  mysql_num_rows($result);
}

function print_secure_content()
{
print("<b><h1>Hi mr.$_SESSION[user]</h1>");
 print "<br><h2>Only a logged in user can see this</h2><br><a href='index.htm'>Počni       kviz</a><br><br><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a><br>";    

}
?>
```

This is where i insert his data to db

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tacni (id_tacnog, id_pitanja, id_korisnik,stanje) VALUES ('', '".$row['odg_id']."','$id_korisnika','tačan')";
////$id_korisnika means id_user
```

And here is where i retrieve from db

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT pitanja.*,tacni.*,korisnici.*
FROM pitanja
INNER JOIN tacni ON pitanja.id = tacni.id_pitanja
INNER JOIN korisnici ON pitanja.id = korisnici.id
 WHERE korisnici.id = '$id_korisnika'");
```

I need to recognize which user is logged in,his answers have to be inserted into a table korisnici(users) which has an id field.i tried like this but nothing happens,no rows have been inserted.Can anyone help me out,and write me a few lines of code that would make this work,i will greatly appreciate any help?

Comment: Your script is open to SQL Injection. And please atleast use POST while sending the password across. And you are using sessions (although not correctly, IMO) to identify logged in user. What do you want exactly?

Comment: try some mysql_error() after inserting and selecting to verify that the queries were completed, and also output the query after you format it to see if it's not missing any data.

Comment: I know,i am just using it for the college,so it doesn't really matter if it is POST or GET.i have this statement after the query if ($num == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so i am exiting"; and that is what i get,it can't insert data in a table,cause it's not getting user id..
    exit;

Answer (score 2):

1. Please use HTTP/POST and not HTTP/GET for posting across the credentials.
2. Your script is using mysql_* functions, and the way you are using it is open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use MySQL's [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead.
3. Try using `$_SESSION["user"]` instead of `$_SESSION[user]`. That will in my opinion fix your problems. Wherever you want to find out which user you are dealing with, use `$_SESSION["user"]` to identify.

Comment: Not working,i think i am not doing something right here $_SESSION["user_id"]=$row['id']; i tried to get his id from a table like this

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using cookies for the purpose.

Comment: Thanks.Can you please tell me how to?